# Original reference for the correspondence between commutative algebraic theories and commutative monads

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads, algebraic-theory

[Commutative algebraic theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory) were introduced by Linton in the 1966 paper [Autonomous Equational Categories](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24901425). [Commutative monads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+monad#tensorial_strengths_and_commutative_monads) were introduced by Kock in the 1970 paper [Monads on symmetric monoidal closed categories](https://math.au.dk/%7Ekock/MSMCC.pdf).

The correspondence between (finitary) algebraic theories and (finitary) monad is known to specialise to a correspondence between (finitary) commutative algebraic theories and (finitary) commutative monads. An explicit reference is Corollary 10.6 of Lucyshyn-Wright's [Commutants for enriched algebraic theories and monads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08569). However, this result must have been known much earlier. Though Kock cites Linton's paper, I could find no reference to commutative algebraic theories in any of his papers on commutative monads. An exercise in Wraith's 1970 [lecture notes](https://www.denotational.co.uk/scans/wraith-algebraic-theories.pdf) on algebraic theories suggests the connection was known, but it is not explicitly stated. A comment at the end of Lindner's paper [Commutative monads](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1975__16_3_217_0.pdf) suggests that, at least in 1975, it was conjectured the two were equivalent, but potentially had been not proven.

Where does a proof of the correspondence between commutative algebraic theories and commutative monads (finitary or infinitary) first appear? (If it is asserted somewhere, but not proven, I would also be interested to know.)

Comment: You're now probably as expert on the 1970s categorical literature as anyone else apart from its actual authors. Anders Kock proved the equivalence between monoidal and commutative monads. He's the person I would ask about the rest of your question, given that Fred Linton is no longer with us.

Comment: Of  course, particularly since you're in Cambridge, you could start by asking Peter Johnstone, who has (had) an extensive card index of categorical facts and literature.

Comment: I emailed Anders Kock and he was unaware of an explicit reference, though he said it was known even as early as the late 1960s.

Comment: A friend of mine told me it was even the 40s. ;)